# Converting NSMutableSet to NSSet

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, nsset, nsmutableset

Is there a way to convert NSMutableSet to NSSet?  I have tried several methods:  moving to an NSArray and the setWithArray; instantiating an NSSet with the contents of the NSMutableSet.  The program compiles but I get a run time error.

```
 NSMutableArray  *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableSet    *num1 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
 NSArray         *num2 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
 NSSet           *num3 = [[NSSet alloc] init];

 num1 = [checkset mutableCopy];  //checkset is of type NSSet
 num2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:NoShows];
 num3 = [NSSet setWithArray:num2];

 [num1 minusSet:num3];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copy` of `NSMutableSet` returns a NSSet

In your sample:

```
NSSet *immutableSet = [checksetM copy]; // returns immutable copy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSSet *)ContainsNoShow:(NSMutableArray *)checkset
{

  NSSet *newcheckset = [[NSSet alloc] init];
  newcheckset = [NSSet setWithArray:NoShows];

  NSMutableSet *checksetM     = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:checkset];

  [checksetM minusSet: newcheckset];

  return checksetM;
```

}